# Changing views in tabbarcontroller is slow

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabbarcontroller that has two viewcontrollers, when I switch to the second one on the app there is an initial lag. Is it because the viewcontroller is loading? If so is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Is it a really complex view? Are you dynamically loading data into it? If you swap your ViewControllers, so the 2nd one is now the 1st one, do you notice the same lag going from 1->2? Or do you then notice lag on initial load, just getting to it to begin with?

Comment: Are you using `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method to set some components? Try to put breakpoints in your methods, maybe you are calling methods recursively.

Comment: I have swapped the viewcontrollers and i get the same lag @DonMag